# Restriction map between Galois groups induces surjection on inertia groups.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $M/L/K$ all be algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q$ and let $P$ be a prime in $\mathcal O_K$, $Q$ be a prime above $P$ in $L$, and $U$ be a prime above $Q$ in $M$. Prove that the map $G(M/K) \twoheadrightarrow G(L/K)$ induces a surjection between the corresponding inertia groups $I(U|P) \longrightarrow I(Q|P)$. Thanks!

Edit:
The fields involved are all arbitrary algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q$, not necessarily finite.

Comment: You probably mean $G(L/K)$.

Comment: Yes, corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\quot}[2]{{\raise{.2em}{#1}\left/\raise{-.2em}{#2}\right.}}$
Here I first assume that the extensions are finite over $\Bbb Q$.
Let $q : G(M/K) \twoheadrightarrow G(L/K)$ be the quotient map (given by the restriction to $L$).

First of all, we easily see that $q(I(U \mid P)) \subset I(Q \mid P)$. Just write the definition of the inertia subgroup.

---

Secondly, we check that $I(Q \mid P) \subset q(I(U \mid P))$.
The kernel of the morphism 
$$q\vert_{ I(U \mid P) } :  I(U \mid P)  \to  I(Q \mid P)$$
is $I(U \mid Q)$. Therefore the quotient
$$ \quot{I(U \mid P)}{I(U \mid Q)} $$
embeds in $I(Q \mid P)$, and the cardinalities of these groups are respectively: $\dfrac{e(U \mid P)}{e(U \mid Q)}$ and $e(Q \mid P)$, where $e(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ denotes the ramification index.

But as you know, ramification indices are multiplicative: $e(U \mid P) = e(U \mid Q) e(Q \mid P)$. This implies that the previous embedding is actually an isomorphism, meaning that $q\vert_{ I(U \mid P) }$ is surjective, i.e. $I(Q \mid P) = q(I(U \mid P))$, as desired.

---

For the general case (with possibly infinite extensions), one can argue using the fact that the Galois groups are profinite groups – the details are explained in [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/676Page/handouts/inertiasurj.pdf) by B. Conrad.

Comment: Thanks! But I had the not necessarily finite case in mind.

Comment: @SameerKulkarni : I edited the answer. Right exactness of inverse limit should hold in our case, as mentionned in _Introduction to Commutative Algebra_, Atiyah and MacDonald, Prop. 10.2, pp. 103-104, because the restrictions $\mathrm{Gal}(M'/K) \to \mathrm{Gal}(M''/K)$ are surjective for any finite subextensions $M' / M'' / K$ of $M/K$.

Comment: With the aid of your comment and edit, I have been able to verify the desired surjection for the case when $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$, but the general case of an arbitrary $K$ remains. I'm still thinking. Your answer was most helpful, and I shall accept it after I see the surjection in the general case. :-)

Comment: Could you deal with the general case for me, please?

Comment: The finite case can be found in Ribenboim, _The Theory of Classical Valuations_, §8.2.I.(a), p. 225. The general case is worked out in Otto Endler, _Valuation theory_, Corollary 19.7., p. 149.

Comment: @SameerKulkarni : you might be interested in reading §19 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=eRzyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA144). See also [the corollary 19.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9EB2.png) and the [cited exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwG9k.png).

Comment: Proposition 1.2.3.1 in _Class Field Theory: From Theory to Practice_, by Georges Gras, might be useful.